# Why does adding parentheses prevent an error?

Tags: javascript, syntax

Why is it when I write `{}.key = 0` in the chrome console I get an error:

```
> {}.key = 0
> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
```

But when I encapsulate the above expression in parentheses (`( )`) I get no error:

```
> ({}.key = 0)
> 0
```

What exactly is going on here? I would have thought the same error I got in the first scenario still applied to the second?

*Image of console output*:

[image]

Comment: One is a statement and one is an expression. As an expression `{}` returns an object. As a statement it is a code block

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`{ }` are overloaded in JavaScript syntax. They're used for both blocks (of statements) and object literals. The rule is: If a `{` appears at the start of a statement, it is parsed as a block; otherwise it is an object literal.

In `{}.key` the `{` appears at the start of the statement. It parses as

```
{
    // this is an empty block
}
.key  // syntax error here
```

Adding any token before `{` (such as `(`) makes it parse as an object literal. For example, `42, {}.key = 0` would also work.

Comment: Actually not any token. There are some specific tokens that will work while others such as `;` and `[]` don't work. The key is not adding token before `{}` but forcing `{}` to be evaluated in expression context. Which means things like `+` and braces will work

Comment: @slebetman I meant within the same statement, obviously. `;` is a statement of its own, so in `;{}` the `{` is still at the start of a statement. `[]` would work, though.

Comment: Note that the console does some additional stuff (it wraps some expressions), thats why `{}.key = {}` and `{ content }` work without parens.

Comment: @JonasWilms when you say console do you mean the snippet console?

Comment: No. `[]` produces syntax error: `[]{}` - syntax error: unexpected token `{`. The problem is precisely because `{}` is a block in statement context but an object literal in expression context.

Comment: @shnick no the chrome console.

Comment: The `()` are forcing the evaluation of the `{}` into a object literal. They are one of the ["primary expressions"](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-grouping-operator-runtime-semantics-evaluation) in the spec. Not just "any symbol" will make this work. But since the `()` hold a special purpose, these will also work: `({}).key = 0; ({}.key) = 0;`

Comment: @slebetman Sure that's a syntax error; you can't just put two values next to each other. But e.g. `[{}.key = 0]` will work fine.